# Excel VBA ADODB sql query using CTE returning no records

Tags: vba, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my first question on Stack Overflow.  I have learned a lot from from this site but I have not been able to find the answer for a problem I am having.

I have a SQL query that works in SQL Server 2008 R2 management studio but it does not work when I query it using vba in EXCEL 2013.  The query contains a common table expression and it is not returning any records to my recordset.

The SQL query is:

```
WITH cte AS 
( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [partNumber] 
ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS i FROM [myDB].[dbo].[PartOrders] 
WHERE [partDescription] like '%motor%' )

SELECT * FROM cte WHERE i = 1
```

I have a reference for Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library

The VBA code I am using is:

```
Dim conn as ADODB.Connection
Dim sql as String
Dim rst as ADODB.Recordset

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
conn.Open

sql = ";WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY " & _
      "[partNumber] ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS i " & _
      "FROM [myDB].[dbo].[PartOrders]" & _
      "WHERE [partDescription] like '%motor%' ) " & _
      "SELECT * FROM cte WHERE i = 1 "

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open sql, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

debug.print rst.recordcount

conn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing
```

My code prints a "-1" in the Immediate window

I have added the preceding ";" to my query based on a recommendation of another questions response.  It does not make a difference.

I have verified the following query string returns a recordset:

```
sql = "SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY " & _
      "[partNumber] ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS i " & _
      "FROM [myDB].[dbo].[partNumbers]" & _
      "WHERE [partDescription] like '%motor%'"
```

I am using a CTE due to needing to collect entire records of a table but only of distinct part descriptions.  I do not want to see that a motor was ordered 20 times.  I would like to see that the motor was was ordered at least once along with the other fields associated with it.  I am searching a table with 730,000 records where there are records for 10,000 motors but only 500 distinct types.

I am open to using a different query if it will net the same results but I am really curious as to why my current query is not yielding any records.  I hope it is not due to an ADODB and VBA incompability.

Thank you for all of the help I have received from others questions and I appreciate any help you can provide me.

Comment: I tried and tried but cannot reproduce your issue though I use MSSQL 2012. Exact SQL (different tables) and same VBA objects and properties. Recordcount returns positive number fine. What is the *Driver* in connection string (the only other variable to test)? Regardless of record count does query return anything?

Comment: I do not have a driver setting in the connection string... My obfuscated connection string is...  "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=server.address;uid=user;pwd=password;Initial Catalog=myDB".   The query does not return anything regardless of record count.

Comment: Wow! Even using *Provider* I cannot recreate your issue. Maybe you should try Driver:  `DRIVER={SQL Server};server=server;database=myDB;UID=user;PWD=password;` Try using the derived table (alternative to CTE): `SELECT main.* FROM (SELECT ...) AS main WHERE main.i = 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Parfait** provided a solution for me in the comments to my original question.  Changing my connection string provider to a driver did not work.  It caused a `Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'`

Instead of a CTE, I utilized a derived table in my query.

The SQL query that returns a recordcount for me in VBA is:

```
SELECT main.*
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [partNumber] 
ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS i FROM [myDB].[dbo].[PartOrders] 
WHERE [partDescription] like '%motor%') 
AS main WHERE main.i = 1
```

Thank You!

Comment: This must be the MSSQL version (i.e., 2008 R2) and/or its interaction with `OLEDB Provider` though it is baffling why as CTEs were introduced in SQL Server 2005! If you have access to later version (2012/2014/2016), try the CTE on your end.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue except I was using Driver as recommended by user7638417.  When the recordset returned, the recordcount was -1, but, when I inserted the rows into the spreadsheet, they were all there (24).  Used simplified query in example, actual query was more complex which lead me to the CTE method.

```
    Dim sql As String
    Dim dbConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim dbRS As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim rows As Integer

    sql = "WITH S1 AS ( SELECT Lot, CollectDt, Mark, Slot, Thick1, Thick2 From Table1 )"
    sql = sql + " WHERE Lot = 'lotnumber' "
    sql = sql + " SELECT * FROM S1 WHERE Thick2 <> "UNKNOWN" ORDER BY Slot "

    dbConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={SQL Server};server=myserver;database=production;uid=guest;pwd=guest"
    dbConn.Open
    dbConn.CommandTimeout = 600
    dbRS.Open sql, dbConn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
        
    Dim totRow As Integer
    totRow = dbRS.RecordCount + 2

   ' If (dbRS.RecordCount > 0) Then
        Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset dbRS
   ' End If
```

I had to comment out the check for data in order to get the data from the record set. The  value in totRow came back as 1 instead of 26, the expected value which causes other things to fail later in the code.
SQL Server Version: 13.0.4001.0
Excel Version: 2016